# How To Solve Editext in More Numbers in a Layout And Get Values From That?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-edittext

See this picture:

[image]

I am designing a sudoku in android, have done the layout like this, so 81 Editext is there. I want to get all the values in the Editext so its difficult to declare and mange 81 views in activity. Can you suggest me a method which is effective for processing my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use array of Edittext's like this

```
EditText text1,text2,text3,text4,text5,text6,text7,text8,text9, text21,text22,text23,text24....text 99;
EditText[] fields={text1,text2,text3,text4,text5,text6,text7,text8,text9, text21,text22,text23,text24....text 99};
//Give your edittext ids in ids array like this
int ids[]={R.id.text1,R.id.text2,R.id.text3.....R.id,text99};
int values[9][9]={};

for(int i=0;i<fiends.length;i++)
{
fields[i]=(EditText)findViewById(ids[i]);
}
```

To get values use the same way take an array and save those values in array like this.
use for loop and get the values from the textfields and save it in the 2d array as i have declared in values array. I suppose you know how to code the rest of the thing you really want to know please comment, I'll post the rest.thank u.. I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 2):

Create edittexts dynamically.

In every iteration you are rewriting the `ed` variable, so when loop is finished `ed` only points to the last EditText instance you created.

You should store all references to all EditTexts:

```
EditText ed;
List<EditText> allEds = new ArrayList<EditText>();

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {   

    ed = new EditText(Activity2.this);
    allEds.add(ed);
    ed.setBackgroundResource(R.color.blackOpacity);
    ed.setId(id);   
    ed.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    linear.addView(ed);
}
```

Now `allEds` list hold references to all EditTexts, so you can iterate it and get all the data.

getting data

```
 String[] strings = new String[](allEds.size());

for(int i=0; i < allEds.size(); i++){
    string[i] = allEds.get(i).getText().toString();
}
```

**NOTE**:

This is not results your design there may be some changes.but follow these procedure to get exact results. I think you must you use `two for loops` to get your edittexts in a gridview.

Comment: id=? what i want to put ??

Answer (score 0):

You can try out this way:

> ```
> public static ArrayList<EditText> m_arr_edit= = new ArrayList<EditText>();
>   RelativeLayout p_rl_layout=new RelativeLayout(m_context);
>   RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
>   LinearLayout  m_ll_timelayout = new LinearLayout(m_context);
>   m_ll_timelayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
>     for (int i = 0; i < p_intervals; i++)
>     {
>         EditText m_edit = new EditText(m_context);
>         m_edit.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(90, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
>         m_edit.setText("Set Text");
>         m_edit.setId(i);
>         m_arr_edit.add(m_btn);
>         m_ll_timelayout.addView(m_btn); 
>     }
>     layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW);
>     p_rl_layout.addView(m_ll_timelayout, layoutParams);
> ```

I hope it will help you.